# Input as List of dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
str_arr = input()
    d = "}, "

    for line in str_arr:
        new_str = [e + '},' for e in str_arr.split(d) if e]

    print(len(new_str))
    for i in new_str:
        print(i)
```

I want my code to accept a list of dictionaries but the input is a string and tried to make the input str_list to a list but my code adds }, at the end of the console output how can I remove it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, should you simply do:

```
new_str = [eval(e.strip()) for e in str_arr.split(",")]
```

I assume that `str_arr` is an input like `{"A":1},{"B":2,"C":3}`, in other words, a string of comma separated dictionaries

Comment: [`eval is evil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4985099), avoid using instead you could use `json.loads`

Comment: can you show me how to use json.load implementation tried but my code had an error

Comment: yes, Lemmi try it

Comment: `new_str = [eval(e.strip()) for e in str_arr.split(",")]` got a an error      ` new_str = [eval(e.strip()) for e in str_arr.split(",")]
  File "<string>", line 1
    [{"bus_id" : 128
                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
`